# Write In A File at Specific Location

Tags: files, text-processing

I am trying to create a script that will add a user to the `UserDir enabled` list or will remove it from `UserDir disabled` list in `userdir.conf`.

For the sake of my question, let's say I have the following file:

```
Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum
    List 1 enabled
Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum
    List 2 disabled
Lorem ipsum
```

What I would like to do is when I run my script with the following `./script enabled user` is to modify my file to:

```
Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum
    List 1 enabled user
Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum
    List 2 disabled
Lorem ipsum
```

Afterwards, if I do `./script disabled user` it will remove user from List 1 and add it two list 2. Thus, the output of the file would be:

```
Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum
    List 1 enabled
Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum
    List 2 disabled  user
Lorem ipsum
```

My question is not about how to write this script, it is about **how to add/delete text into/from a file at a specific location**.

**Off-topic question:** Is there a better way to add/remove users in the UserDir list of the apache2?

Comment: I've tried doing it like this: `tr '/s/UserDir enabled/UserDir enabled user/' userdir.conf>userdir.conf` but apparently this will delete my file.

Comment: *"apparently this will delete my file"* Not exactly, it'll open the output target file for create/write before the command is actually executed. Also, you almost certainly want sed instead of tr. Look up sed's `-i` option for an alternative that just might work.

Comment: I meant to say sed not tr

Comment: What aspect of apache2 are you dealing with here? also what's your linux distro you're running Apache2 on?

Comment: I am dealing with userdir (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_userdir.html) module and I am running on Debian 6.0. However my issue is not much related to how to add/remove users from the UserDir list manually, it's rather much more related to automate it with a shell script.

Comment: _"...off-topic question"_ I'd say that is better asked in a separate thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `sed` or `awk`. Take your pick. Personally, I like to use the tool with the smallest footprint. You can, of course, do it in any programming language like Perl, C, SNOBOL or PDP-8 machine code, but this may be ever so slightly beyond the scope of the question. ;)

To delete a user from the `UserDir enable` line using sed:

```bsh
sed -e '/^[^#]*UserDir\s\+enabled\s\+/ s/\bfoo\b//g' -e 's/\s\+/ /g' FILE-IN >FILE-OUT
```

This does two things:

1. For all lines that start with a non-commented out `UserDir enabled`, it removes the user `foo` (but not, for example, a user `foobar`).
2. It removes superfluous white space.

To add a user:

```bsh
sed -e '/^[^#]*UserDir\s+enabled\s+/ s/\(\s\+#\|$\)/ bar\1/' FILE-IN >FILE-OUT
```

This will look for all lines like `Userdir enabled` that isn't commented out, same as before. For any such lines found, it will add the user `bar` at the end. If the line ends in a comment, the comment is respected and left in there.

To add a new `UserDir enabled` line after the `UserDir disabled` line:

```bsh
sed -e '/^[^#]*UserDir\s+enabled\s+/ a UserDir disabled foo bar baz' FILE-IN >FILE-OUT
```

This uses the append (`a`) `sed` command to add text *after* every non-commented-out line like `UserDir enabled ...`. Change the `a` to an `i` to insert *before* the matched line.

Some notes:

- Obviously, change ‘enabled’ to ‘disabled’ at will.
- We use `\s+` instead of spaces to catch cases where other forms of white space are used (e.g. tabs), and/or multiple white space characters are encountered.
- You can combine both operations. Sed can run multiple expressions on each file. Each expression is provided after the `-e` option and they run in order, from left to right.
- Note that some characters that aren't escaped in some regular expression dialects *are* escaped for the regular expression flavour used by `sed`.
- These will require a temporary file (`FILE-OUT`) to store the edited file (`FILE-IN`).
  If you want to invoke these in-place (without redirecting to a temporary file), replace the `FILE-IN >FILE-OUT` with `-i FILE`.
- These work for sure on Linux. Your mileage may vary with `sed` versions from other Unices. You may find `-i` (above) isn't available and that regular expression support is more limited.

Off-topic answer: it would so much easier if Apache would let you enter multiple `UserDir` directives and added up the user lists. It may do that, but a cursory check came up blank. I've never had to do this, so I'm not sure whether is possible.

Comment: Ok, this work fairly good. Thank you very much! However, I have one more question. How can I add a new line with `UserDir enabled` right after `UserDir disabled`?

Comment: You're welcome! I updated the answer, things can get a bit cramped in the comments.

Comment: Thanks again! :) And it would go the same way for adding disabled right after disabled (just inverse enabled with disabled), right? :D

Comment: Absolutely. You can change the regexp patterns at will (of course).

Answer (score 0):

Such tasks are simpler being solved re-creating the file from source(s). It looks like pre-processing and it's a way more effective to build the result from sources instead of patching resulting file.